# Access Denied (403) with ordered cache in Cloudfront s3 distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I am trying to add multiorigin setup with cloudfront with ordered cache behaviour. Here is what i want to achieve(given my baseurl is https://example.com/

1. https://example.com/ shows index.html from root bucket.(root_app)
2. https://example.com/app2 shows index.html from another bucket (app2)

For this, I created a CF s3 distribution with two origins (root, app2) pointing to two different buckets. In the cache behavior, I have created ordered cache behavior to route all traffic with path "app2*" to app2 origin.

With this setup https://example.com/ is landing me to root_app but https://example.com/app2 is throwing below error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>E1C4FA78C620F166</RequestId>
<HostId>nwVnR036HRHWVwiQoEoJQaj9A/Mf975SUYOoiYrgX8JasQCEWRrEeNTvBM5y327gZzcfCLksCDY=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I see below http response headers in the browser for above request

```
content-type: application/xml
date: Sun, 06 Sep 2020 06:34:06 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 403
via: 1.1 45645ff3269a2b885ffa1653e827d0f7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: vVTtxpNxuilWppQ2mskMvN-p7fbNBM8DqHvVYQMYV8-kH-4GVtRHNw==
x-amz-cf-pop: SFO20-C1
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

Any idea what's wrong with this flow?

Comment: Seems the second bucket denies the access. Is it set to public with bucket policy, or how did you set it up?

Comment: It is set to allow public access. index.html file is also public.

Comment: @Krishnom review the S3 logs for **both** buckets to find the request coming in from CloudFront.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how CloudFront routing works. When there is a request to `example.com/app2`, then it forwards the request to `<bucket2>/app2` instead of `<bucket2>`. You see this error because it's not the index.html you'd expect.

You can move the files in bucket2 into an `app2` folder and then change the path pattern to `/app2/*`. This way the request to `example.com/app2/` will go to `<bucket2>/app2/` which is where your files are.

Alternatively, you can use Lambda@Edge to rewrite the origin request path for every request going to bucket2. I [wrote an article](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-lambda-edge-with-terraform/#example-code) how to solve a similar case.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas Though, not what i expected but That did work. (creating folder for path in second bucket). As you said Lambda@Edge is an option here and that is the one i will prefer to go with. I read the doc and found Lambda URl rewrite to be a long term solution that can fit in terraform flow.